# How do I remove the newline from the last line in a file in order to add text to that line?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, newlines

Suppose  I have a file called `file`:

```
$ cat file
Hello
Welcome to
Unix
```

I want to add `and Linux` at the end of the last line of the file. If I do `echo " and Linux" >> file` will be added to a new line. But I want last line as `Unix and Linux`

So, in order to work around this, I want to remove newline character at the end of file. Therefore, how do I remove the newline character at the end of file in order to add text to that line?

Comment: Don't remove it, just use a text editor. `sed '$s/$/ and linux/'`

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If all you want to do is add text to the last line, it's very easy with sed. Replace `$` (pattern matching at the end of the line) by the text you want to add, only on lines in the range `$` (which means the last line).

```
sed '$ s/$/ and Linux/' <file >file.new &&
mv file.new file
```

which on Linux can be shortened to

```
sed -i '$ s/$/ and Linux/' file
```

If you want to remove the last byte in a file, Linux (more precisely GNU coreutils) offers the [`truncate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/truncate.1.html) command, which makes this very easy.

```
truncate -s -1 file
```

A POSIX way to do it is with `dd`. First determine the file length, then truncate it to one byte less.

```
length=$(wc -c <file)
dd if=/dev/null of=file obs="$((length-1))" seek=1
```

Note that both of these unconditionally truncate the last byte of the file. You may want to check that it's a newline first:

```
length=$(wc -c <file)
if [ "$length" -ne 0 ] && [ -z "$(tail -c -1 <file)" ]; then
  # The file ends with a newline or null
  dd if=/dev/null of=file obs="$((length-1))" seek=1
fi
```

Comment: Much better [way to remove a trailing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1654042/2388257#how-can-i-delete-a-newline-if-it-is-the-last-character-in-a-file) is `perl -pi -e 'chomp if eof' myfile`. Compared to `truncate` or `dd` it not gonna leave you with a broken file if `myfile` had actually no trailing newlines.

Comment: @Hi-Angel May I recommend writing that as an answer? I think that would be a very good answer.

Answer (score 65):

You can achieve this with perl as:

```bsh
perl -pi -e 'chomp if eof' myfile
```

Compared to `truncate` or `dd` this not gonna leave you with a broken file if `myfile` had actually no trailing newlines.

*(the answer is constructed from [the comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254644/how-do-i-remove-newline-character-at-the-end-of-file/254753?noredirect=1#comment963520_254753), and based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1654042/2388257#how-can-i-delete-a-newline-if-it-is-the-last-character-in-a-file))*

Comment: Thank-you! This conditional method of removing is trailing newline is perfect.

Comment: Best answer. Too bad for everyone that you were late to the party.

Comment: best answer!  Also to make this easy to use, I just defined a little function like this: `function chomp() { perl -p -e 'chomp if eof' }`.  Now I can strip a new line with a pipe like this: `cat /tmp/file | chomp`.

Answer (score 59):

Though, you can remove newline character from all lines by using `tr -d '\n'`:

```
$ echo -e "Hello"
Hello
$ echo -e "Hello" | tr -d '\n'
Hello$
```

You can remove the newline character at the end of file using following easy way:

1. **`head -c -1 file`**

From `man head`:

```
    -c, --bytes=[-]K
              print the first K bytes of each file; with the leading '-',
              print all but the last K bytes of each file
```

2. **`truncate -s -1 file`**

from `man truncate`:

```
    -s, --size=SIZE
              set or adjust the file size by SIZE
```

SIZE is an integer and optional unit (example: 10M is 10*1024*1024).
        Units are K, M, G, T, P, E, Z, Y (powers of 1024) or KB, MB, ... (powers of 1000).
    
        SIZE  may  also be prefixed by one of the following modifying characters: 
        '+' extend by, '-' reduce by, '' at least, '/' round down to multiple of, '%' round up to multiple of.

Comment: is `head -c -1 file | tee file` safe? Wouldn't `tee` truncate the file before starting?

Comment: @1_CR Indeed. The two sides of the pipe start in parallel, it's a matter of who wins the race. Since `tee` only has to open the file, whereas `head` has to read and write its contents, `tee` will in practice win the race except sometimes for very small files.

Comment: This doesn't remove last newline, it remove all newlines. IMO quite a big difference.

Comment: Solution 2 should be the accepted answer. If your file is huge you really do not want to read the full file.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way with `sed` -- on the last (`$`) line of the file, search and replace anything and everything (`.*`) with "whatever you matched" followed by " and Linux":

```
sed '$s/\(.*\)/\1 and Linux/' file
```

An even simpler solution, courtesy of [Isaac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/265604/isaac), is:

```
sed '$s/$/ and Linux/' file
```

This replaces the (symbolic) end-of-line with the given text.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -0pi -e "s/\R\z//g" file
```

Works for "\r" (MAC), "\r\n" (Windows) and "\n" (Linux).
For repeated newlines (any tipe) at end of file you can do:

```
perl -0pi -e "s/\R*\z//g" file
```